# How can I discourage gluttony while still granting buffs?

Tags: gm-techniques, house-rules, feast-of-legends

In Wendy's Feast of Legends, characters gain bonuses for foods eaten by their players.

The game explicitly mentions that buffs stack and there are a total 6 different food items (briefly: burger, chicken, frosty, drink, fries, salad).

A particularly health-reckless power-gamer could gorge themselves on  in order to gain limitless bonuses. Of course the intersection between power gamers and players of Wendy's Feast of Legends should be fairly small, but even so.

It also feels unscrupulous to deny bonuses to someone that brought their own food that doesn't fall into those categories (soup, for example), or doesn't consume certain food items (beef, for example).

**How can I fairly offer buffs (and debuffs?) without directly involving player-food-consumption?**

Comment: Only a matter of time until the wrongful death suits start piling against Wendy's.  "My son was only 22, but he ate himself into a heart attack playing *Feast of Legends*."

Comment: Either that, or the game will inadvertently train power gamers into pro-level competitive eaters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 1. Don't use that rule

["Feast of Legends"](https://www.feastoflegends.com/images/Feast_Of_Legends.pdf) is deliberately silly with much of it being somewhat "tongue in cheek". Personally, I wouldn't use the rules about buffs based on real life food at all (they are page 10, incidentally). This completely removes any concerns about directly incentivizing gluttony or directly involving player-food-consumption.

### 2. Limit it to 3 items

A normal Wendy's meal, and indeed most fast food meals, have 3 items. To avoid issues, you can have a house rule capping it at 3 items total if you want to use those rules at all. This places a firm limit on how many buffs or debuffs players could gain. Whether this is fair or not depends entirely on your definition of fair.

### 3. Don't worry about it

As you correctly noted, the overlap between power-gamers and people that are going to play "Feast of Legends" in a serious way is very small. You would also expect most people to be somewhat self-limiting in how much they eat regardless.

This most likely will not be a real problem at your table even using these rules as written. This is especially true in a game that is meant to be silly to a certain degree so granting even large buffs will not likely destroy the fun of the game which is far more in its silliness and absurdity than in careful tactical decision and the stacking of buffs.

Comment: Are you sure that promoting gluttony isn't a feature of the game? :D

Comment: @NautArch A game released by a fast food chain encouraging people to eat fast food? Naaaaah!

Comment: I would not allow this rule either. It is a badly designed rule which only has one apparent goal: sell fast food. We never needed in game bonuses to get and share our food during games ...until Wendys made a PR stunt aimed at RPers. It's kinda shameless.

Comment: @Catar4 to be fair, the idea of bribing the DM with food for in-game bonuses has been an RPG meme for a long time.

Comment: Have you ever used a rule like this before? What was your experience with it?

Comment: @Carcer yes indeed, we used to joke about bribing with food. And now we have a corporation who wants to make it more than a joke/meme to sell their fast food. I don't like it, personally. As much because it is badly designed than because it is nothing other than a cash grab.

Answer (score -1):

You could limit it to a dollar amount.  With $10 a player can buy a lot of small fries or 9 mini frosties.  I think if you buff up too much the game becomes too easy.  It is already designed to give the characters plenty of opportunities to increase their abilities and stats.

Comment: Hello, Nik! Here on [RPG.SE], we expect answerers to tell us how they have personally used the tips they give. Untested solutions are usually frowned upon and downvoted. Could you please tell us how you have personally used your solution in this game?